# "Circular" object argument in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

Say I am given a linked list (Java) with definition,

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

I am given an instance of the linked list:

```
1->2->3->4
```

In this function below I am given access to the **node with value 3** Ie. `3`

```
public void remove (ListNode node){
    node = node.next;
}
```

Does the linked list become `1->2->4`?

I tried submitting this solution to an online judge and it didn't do anything. Help?

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: @Omore, `1->2->3->4`, didnt change anything

Comment: Code will do nothing, since you're just changing the value of the parameter variable, not any fields of any objects.

Answer (score 1):

Java parameters are `passed by value`.

When you call `remove`, a copy of the reference to `node` is passed in. Your code attempts to change this reference locally by setting `node = node.next()`, but this won't affect the original list.

What the `remove` method needs to do is locate the node in the list that has a `next` that refers to the node you want to remove, and change that to point to the node after the node you want to remove. Assuming there's a method to find the parent of a given node called `findParentOf()`:

```
ListNode parentNode = findParentOf(nodeToRemove);
parentNode.next = nodeToRemove.next;
```

Comment: A reference is passed in though, so it should mutate the original shouldnt it

Comment: I see what you are saying I think. All we do when we say `node = node.next` is change what node is pointing to correct?

Comment: @fasasa A copy of the reference is passed in. If you set the local copy to refer to another node, it won't change the original list.

Comment: Yes, a reference is passed in, but you're not modifying the referenced object - you're changing the value of the reference itself. That is, you're making it point to a different object, without actually changing any of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void remove (ListNode node){
    node = node.next;
}
```

This will only affect the local reference you are currently holding. To remove a node, you have to manipulate the `next` variable of its predecessor, which is not available, as it is a single-linked list.

All you can theoretically do is:

```
public void removeNext (ListNode node) {
    node.next = node.next.next;
}
```

When calling this method on your sample list you'll have to use the node with value 2, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void remove (ListNode node){
    node = node.next;
}
```

it doesn't do anything because when local reference variable `node` is set to `node.next`, it goes from pointing to the node with val of 3 to to the node with val of 4.

```
      ||
      \/    
1->2->3->4
```

becomes

```
         ||
         \/
1->2->3->4
```